# Nested jQuery carousel conflict

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, carousel

i'm trying to use 2 nested jquery carousel but the second carousel doesn't work.
when i go to the item that contain the second carousel it seems to change item too.
in other words: i click the div that go to the third item (that contain the second carousel) and the second carousel change item too.
The problem is the second carousel go to an unknown item and so show nothing

this is the simplified code:

HTML

```
<div class="carousel slide" id="myCarousel" data-bs-interval="false">
    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    
        <div class="item active">

            <div class="content-item">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">

            <div class="content-item">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">

            <div class="content-item">
                <div class="proposal-list">
                    <div class="proposal-list-item socializzazione">Socializzazione</div>
                    <div class="proposal-list-item pre-adozione">Consulenze pre-adozione</div>
                    <div class="proposal-list-item Educazione">Educazione di base/avanzata</div>
                    <div class="proposal-list-item Passeggiate">Passeggiate educative</div>
                </div>
                <div class="carousel slide" id="proposalCarousel" data-bs-interval="false">
                    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
                    
                        <div class="item active">
                        </div>

                        <div class="item ">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  

// MAIN PAGE
    // Activate Carousel
  var myCarousel = $("#myCarousel").carousel({
      interval: false
  });  

  // Enable Carousel Indicators
  $(".home").on("click", function(){
    myCarousel.carousel(0);
  });
  $(".esperienze").on("click", function(){
    myCarousel.carousel(1);
  });
  $(".proposte").on("click", function(){
    myCarousel.carousel(2);
  });
  $(".contatti").on("click", function(){
    myCarousel.carousel(3);
  });
  

  // THIRD PAGE
  var proposalCarousel = $("#proposalCarousel").carousel({
    interval: false
  });


  $(".socializzazione").on("click", function(){
    proposalCarousel.carousel(0);
  });
  $(".pre-adozione").on("click", function(){
    proposalCarousel.carousel(1);
  });
  $(".Educazione").on("click", function(){
    proposalCarousel.carousel(2);
  });
  $(".Passeggiate").on("click", function(){
    proposalCarousel.carousel(3);
  });
  
});
```

What did i do wrong?

Sorry if there's already a thread about this argument, i didn't find it

Comment: Please tell us what carousel library/plugin this is supposed to be using.

Comment: apologize, i'm using the standard bootstrap library:
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

Comment: Since you are using click handlers on the slides here, I am guessing this is simply an issue of these click events bubbling up from the inner to the outer slide. Either stop the event propagation in your inner slider click handlers (https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/), or check what the event target was in your outer slider click handlers, before you switch to the next slide.

Comment: @PaoloPellizzari can you provide reproduceable code. I am unable to generate carousel with the code you provide.

Comment: I think the carousel does somethings like this:
$( carouselID + ' .item.active').removeClass('active');
So every div with the class active will be efected.
I'll do some more tests

Comment: As I said the carousel remove to all ".item.active" the class active. I think the carousel is not meant to be nested.
I will use a workaround, thanks to all of you